# Gridsearch with LightGBM verbose displays just one line

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, lightgbm, gridsearchcv

I've been running a Randomized Grid Search in sklearn with LightGBM in Sagemaker, but when I run the `fit` line, it only displays one message that says `Fitting 3 folds for each of 100 candidates, totalling 300 fits` and nothing more, no messages showing the process or metrics.

Here's the code that I am using:

```
fit_params={#'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
        #"objective":'binary',
        "eval_metric" : 'auc',            
        "eval_set" : [(X_test,y_test)],
        'eval_names': ['valid'],
        'verbose': 60,
        #'is_unbalance':True,
        #'n_estimators':10000,
        "early_stopping_rounds":500, 
        'categorical_feature': 'auto'}

from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint
from scipy.stats import uniform as sp_uniform
param_test ={'num_leaves': sp_randint(6, 50), 
         'max_depth': sp_randint(3, 9),             
         'min_child_samples': sp_randint(150, 600),             
         'min_child_weight': [1e-5, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4],
         'learning_rate': sp_uniform(loc=0.001, scale=0.01),
         'subsample': sp_uniform(loc=0.2, scale=0.8),
         'colsample_bytree': sp_uniform(loc=0.4, scale=0.6),
         'reg_alpha': [0, 1e-1, 1e-2, 5e-2, 0.5, 0.25, 1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 50, 100],
         'reg_lambda': [0, 1e-1, 1e-2, 5e-2, 0.5, 0.25, 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
         'class_weight': [None, 'balanced']
        }

n_HP_points_to_test = 100

clf1 = lgb.LGBMClassifier(boosting_type='gbdt', metric='None', objective='binary', 
                      is_unbalance=True, n_estimators=10000, random_state=314, n_jobs=40)

gs1 = RandomizedSearchCV(
estimator=clf1, param_distributions=param_test, 
n_iter=n_HP_points_to_test,
scoring='roc_auc',
cv=3,
refit=True,
random_state=314,
n_jobs=30,
verbose=100)
```

And the final line to fit and launch the Search:

```
gs1.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
```

I've read other questions and they say that the output is being printed on the log terminal, but I don't seem to find it in Sagemaker neither on my local machine.

Has any of you come across this situation when searching for the optimal parameters? Do you have another piece of code to run this GridSearchCV or RandomizedSearchCV that works for you and LightGBM?

Forgot to mention that the fitting never finishes, I even coded a line to print the `best_params_` to a .txt file, and it never showed, besides all the cores that I used, like 40, were still busy on `htop`, but 15 hours for this process seems kinda excessive.

Thank you so much in advance!!